# How can I create a partition for OSX without erasing other partions on the disk?

Tags: partitioning, osx-lion, disk-utility

I'm trying to install OS Lion on my desktop using uniBeast. I want OSX to be on the same disk as my Windows 7 installation, but the installer's disk utility won't let me create a new partition out of the free space on the drive- all the options (including +/-) are greyed out when any one partition is selected. The only way it allows me to create a new partiton is be repartitioning the entire drive, thus destroying my windows installation. I've been trying to find something in the diskutil man page on how to use free space but I've had no luck :( At the moment I have a 150GB windows partition with a 100mb system reserve, the remaining 170GB is free. Thanks.

Comment: [GParted LiveCD](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php)

Comment: Which model Mac is this?

Comment: It's my custom built pc - I just can't bear to use windows anymore :(. I think theres something seriously wrong with my hard drive. I haven't been able to view it with any disk management tool- they all say the entire drive is unallocated and needs to be formatted :/